# Extracting two Inputbox values separated by a hyphen and forming a number range with them

Tags: excel, vba

Here's a little different one. I am not the greatest with VBA but I like to learn and mess around with it. I'm making an Inputbox where the user can put in a range (say 1-100) using a hyphen as a separator. I want the VBA to extract the two values separately from either side of the hyphen and then use those two values to create a range output that shows all the values between them (for example 1-100 would output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc into the specified cell). I have made the code and it works.

However it only works if I put the range between 1-99. If I do that it works great. If I do 1-100 it doesn't do anything. If I do 5-50 it doesnt do anything. It has to be a 1 as the first number and no higher than 99. This is where I'm stuck and don't know how to fix it.

It also allows the person to put in individual numbers with a comma separator (eg 2,4,6,8).

Here's my code.

```
Sub KeepRowsUnmodified()

Dim myValue As Variant, name As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Specify the test numbers individually by using a comma separator(1,2,3,4,5), or enter a range by using a hyphen(1-10).")
IndiTestNo = Split(myValue, ",")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value = ","
    End If
    If InStr(1, myValue, "-", vbTextCompare) Then
        Input1 = Left(myValue, InStr(myValue, "-") - 1)
        Input2 = Right(myValue, InStr(myValue, "-"))
        For RangeInput = Input1 To Input2
        ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value & RangeInput & ","
        Next
    Else
    For Each name In IndiTestNo
    ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value & name & ","
    Next
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the max number one can input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
Sub Test()

Dim myValue  As Variant: myValue = InputBox("Specify the test numbers individually by using a comma separator(1,2,3,4,5), or enter a range by using a hyphen(1-10).")
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Split(myValue, ",")
Dim x As Long

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(x) Like "*-*" Then
        arr(x) = Join(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & Replace(arr(x), "-", ":") & "))"), ",")
    End If
Next x

Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")

End Sub
```

Testing with input `1,2,3,4,5,8-14` > `1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14`

Comment: Excellent arr(x) definition in that specific case ("-")!

Comment: Thank you! That's much better than I could've hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use also the split function:

```
input = Split(myValue, "-")
For rangeInput = input(0) To input(1)
   ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AB5").Value & RangeInput & ","
Next rangeInput
```